# Textareas with dynamically-assigned name throws my code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a number of textareas, each with a unique assigned name (name="adcode$ID", for example). When I try to pass those names to the code below, it doesn't work because of the dynamic part.

```
if (isset($_POST['editadapp'])) {  // Edit AD
$newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['.adcode$ID.']);
$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '".$newadcode."') WHERE ads_ID=$ID" or die(mysql_error());
$updatead = mysql_query($doedit) or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what's that extra parenthesis doing right before the `WHERE`: `de."') WHERE`

Comment: thanks for the spot/info. still learning so the or die( was dumbness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so much wrong with this that it's frightening.

Firstly,

```
$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '".$newadcode."') WHERE ads_ID=$ID" or die(mysql_error());
```

That code snippet is wrong on many levels.

1. The sql syntax is wrong
2. The sql is formatted with strings from user input (see parameterization of queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663287/sql-insert-and-submit/12664894#12664894)
3. or die() should not be used here, you're creating a string

Ideally you should have code like:

```
$dbh =  new PDO('connectionstring to connect to your database');
$sql = 'update ads set adcode = ? where ads_id = ?';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($_POST['adcode' . $ID], $ID));
```

Other topics:

[Are Paramerterized queries necessary in pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881156/are-parameterized-queries-in-pdo-necessary-for-request-variables)

[prepared queries with pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299182/prepared-parameterized-query-with-pdo)

[Preventing sql injection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks!! answers like this help me learn and I bet everyone that is trying to learn! thanks once again..still very new to php. so far one week. so i think I'm doing okish...lol least i hope i am

Comment: i wish i had seen this reply 5 seconds sooner would have save another question...dangit!

Comment: It's no problem, the bigger issue is the abundance of BAD examples on the internet. Feel free to ask any other questions :D

Comment: thanks. hopefully i'll learn FASTER!! and not need anymore help with simple stuff =}

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be attempting string concatenation. Here's how to do that correctly:

```
$newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode' . $ID]);
```

The following line should simply create a string containing your SQL query; you don't execute it until the next line, there is no function call so the `or die` is out of place. You also mix concatenation with interpolation (variable names within a double quoted string) which is fine but probably not helping you understand your syntax issues, so let's be consistent:

```
$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '" . $newadcode . "' WHERE ads_ID = " . $ID;
```

Comment: Also the invalidity of the 3rd line... First, there's an extra parenthesis in the query. Next, he's adding an `or die` where there's no call in the first place.

Comment: Presumably somewhere earlier in his code. If you want to ask him that, you'd probably want to put it in a comment on his question, not this answer.

Comment: $_POST['ID'] should come after if (isset($_POST['editadapp'])) { isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use array like `adcode[<?php echo $ID;?>]` at your page where the text area is and a hidden field `name=adID[$ID]`. At the page where the query executes
`$adID = $_POST['adID'];
    $newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode']);
    $N = count($adID);
    for($i=0;$N<$i;$i++){
    $doedit = mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET adcode = '$newadcode[$i]' WHERE ads_ID=$adID[$i];") or die(mysql_error());`